# While(true) only happens once no errors

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

Pretty straight forward question. My while loop in the thread I created by a button pressed action only happens once and "this" never repeats again. It does receive the first message but future messages are not received as the while loop is stuck. The first message does print out.

Also the switch loop never happens after the message is printed.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread Listener = new Thread(ServerListener);
        Listener.Start();
    }



    public void ServerListener()
    {
        byte[] buf;
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this");
            if (serverStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                buf = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                serverStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                string stringdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
                Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + stringdata);

                switch (stringdata)
                {
                    case "ping":
                        buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("pong");
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent pong");
                        serverStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        serverStream.Flush();
                        break;
                    case "handshake":
                        buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("lol");
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent confirmation");
                        serverStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        serverStream.Flush();
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I am sure someone is going to come and tell me to use tasks. I know how to use tasks but I see no difference between Task with option of longrunning vs a normal thread.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger to see what it's doing?

Comment: Your thread dies with an exception. Catch and inspect it.

Comment: I tried catching any exceptions as Saruman stated below.

Comment: Ignoring the return value of Read() is *never* correct.  The number of bytes you actually get are entirely unpredictable.  What happens next is a wild guess, never anything good.

Comment: I added an int to receive the read... If that makes you happy. Although that doesn't help my loop. I try and caught it and nothing happened because there were no errors (Exceptions).

Comment: I'll reiterate, step through it in the debugger

Comment: Your problem is with your CLIENT I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that I need to Frame my outgoing data. For an example of framing please look at the below code. Framing tells the receiver how much data to expect.

```
   public void SendResponse(int command, Object[] args)
    {
        if (ClientSocket == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command: ClientSocket");
            return;
        }
        var serverStream = this.ClientSocket.GetStream();
        if (!serverStream.CanRead || !serverStream.CanWrite)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command: serverStream Error");
            return;
        }
        byte[] toSend = null;
        switch (command)
        {
            // 0 - genneral, 1 - handshake response
            case 0:
                toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0].ToString());
                break;
            case 1:
                Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    }
                    toSend = ImageToByte(bitmap);
                }
                break;
        }

        try
        {
//--- Framing occurs here mainly
            byte[] bufferedToSend = new byte[toSend.Length + 4];
            byte[] lengthOfSend = BitConverter.GetBytes(toSend.Length);
            Array.Copy(lengthOfSend, bufferedToSend, 4);
            toSend.CopyTo(bufferedToSend, 4);
            serverStream.Write(bufferedToSend, 0, bufferedToSend.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok now I'm posting code which worked

Client :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientSocket = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8001); // Note the change
            Thread Listener = new Thread(ServerListener);
            Listener.Start();
        }

        public void ServerListener()
        {
            byte[] buf;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread started");

            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this");
                if (serverStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    buf = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    serverStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    string stringdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + stringdata);

                    switch (stringdata)
                    {
                        case "ping":
                            buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("pong");
                            Console.WriteLine("Sent pong");
                            serverStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            serverStream.Flush();
                            break;
                        case "handshake":
                            buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("lol");
                            Console.WriteLine("Sent confirmation");
                            serverStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            serverStream.Flush();
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SERVER :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

                TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IP, 8001);
                Listener.Start();

                Socket s = Listener.AcceptSocket();
                Console.WriteLine("Conected");
                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                s.Send(asen.GetBytes("ping"));
                Console.WriteLine("Data sent");

                s.Close();
                Listener.Stop();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM YOU HAD :

I think it was with your SERVER or in codes you didn't show us. Run above Server as a console application and client as winform application.